# Return a null value as placeholder for full column

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I am joining Table1 to itself with a `LEFT JOIN` on columns `year`, `month`, and `market`.

```
 SELECT Source.Month
   ,Source.Year
   ,Source.Price
   ,Data.Price
FROM Table1 As Source
  LEFT JOIN Table1 As Data ON Source.Month = Data.Month
                           AND Source.Year = Data.Year
WHERE Source.Product = 1
  AND Data.Product = 2
```

The target value that I am attempting to populate, `Price`, exists for all months and years for the `Product` in `Source`, but only selected months and years for the `Product` in `Data`. I am trying to get every `year` and `month` to popuate regardless if `Data.Price` exists. I thought it would return `NULL` due to the `LEFT JOIN`, but I think it may have to do with the `WHERE` clause condition.

How can I get `Data.Price` to populate `NULL` in the case that no value for `Price` exists for the selected `Product`?

Comment: Why not just turn your query around and use Data as the basis of your query with a left join to Product?

Comment: I faced this once but I am not sure. Actually, when you apply a filter on a null field, it will just get eliminated from the result set.
For instance, the filter `Data.Product = 2` will eliminate the records having a null value if Product is not available for the non selected `Month` and `Year`
Can you try this 
`NVL(Data.Product,'-99') = 2`

Comment: You are correct.  When the LEFT JOIN cannot find a matching record return it returns NULL.  Because your WHERE clause filters out these NULLs you lose the records.  @Me.Name shows a great approach below.  Or you could amend the WHERE like so: *AND (Data.Product = 2 OR Data.Product IS NULL)*.  The brackets will ensure records are returned that match either expression.

Comment: @Fnayou I'm sure you know this already but you cannot use NVL in SQL Server.  Use [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms184325.aspx) instead.  I've upvoted your comment because it explains what is happening better than my own effort!

Comment: Oh yes correct. Sorry about that and glad I am of a help.

Comment: Actually thinking about a second change is required.   ISNULL(Product, **2**) = 2 would work.  This would swap any returned NULLs for a 2.  As 2 = 2 these records would make their way into the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

`Where` will indeed filter the results, you could add the criterium to the join instead:

```
 SELECT Source.Month
   ,Source.Year
   ,Source.Price
   ,Data.Price
FROM Table1 As Source
  LEFT JOIN Table1 As Data ON Source.Month = Data.Month
                           AND Source.Year = Data.Year
                           AND Data.Product = 2
WHERE Source.Product = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Month, t.Year,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.Product = 1 THEN Price END) as SourcePrice,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.Product = 2 THEN Price END) as DataPrice
FROM Table1 t
WHERE Product IN (1, 2) -- optional
GROUP BY t.Month, t.Year;
```

Note:  This will work regardless of whether one or both products appear during a month.

Actually, an explicit `PIVOT` is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

Create calendar table
or use CTE

```
;WITH Years as (
SELECT 1900 [Year]
UNION ALL
SELECT [Year] + 1 as [Year]
FROM Years
WHERE [Year] < 9999
)
, Months as (
SELECT 1 as [Month] UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10
UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12)
, Calendar as (
SELECT Years.[Year], Months.[Month]
FROM Years
    CROSS JOIN Months
)

SELECT
    Calendar.[Year]
    ,Calendar.[Month]
    ,Source.Price
    ,Data.Price
FROM Calendar
  LEFT JOIN Table1 As Source ON Calendar.Month = Source.Month
                           AND Calendar.Year = Source.Year
                           AND Source.Product = 1
  LEFT JOIN Table1 As Data ON Calendar.Month = Data.Month
                           AND Calendar.Year = Data.Year
                           AND Data.Product = 2
WHERE Calendar.[Year] BETWEEN 2015 and 2016
ORDER BY Calendar.[Year], Calendar.[Month]
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```